# Futurebuilder not updating with the future value as it may be initializing before the data is ready

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, stream-builder

As of now, my futurebuilder never builds, it will remain in the 'Loading'... state forever. If I hot reload, or change something once the app is loaded it does load at that point though. Right now I have it automatically reloading after 1000ms although it's bad code. The stream builder is used to build a list of cards based on the user's location. The list in question - listNearby - is created within the stream builder and is to give me a snapshot of the list of those 8 closest locations, it was the only way I knew how to gather that from the geoflutterfire2 response.

This is a snipped of the code within the widget build (Streambuilder and Futurebuilder):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream =
geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);

return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                      stream: stream,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data != null) {
                          List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>? streamList = snapshot.data?.toList();
                          for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                            var tester = streamList![i].id;
                            courtTest.add(tester);
                            listNearby = List<String>.from(courtTest);
                            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
                              listNearby = List<String>.from(courtTest);
                            });
                          }
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 140,
                            child: ListView.separated(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: 8,
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return const SizedBox(width: 15);
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  ///additional itembuilder stuff
                                  return ///some user interface;
                                }),
                          );
                      }),
                  FutureBuilder(
                    future: getFuture,
                    builder: (_, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data != null) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 140,
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return const SizedBox(width: 15);
                              },
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return buildUpcomingCard(
                                  ///card data
                                );
                              }),
                        );
                      } else {
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                          setState(() {
                            getFuture = getSearch();
                          });
                        });

                        return const Text('Loading...');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

Based on other research, this may be the correct way to initialize the future, although since it's dependent on a future value (listNearby from Streambuilder) here's what I think is happening. The getSearch gets initialized, it sees that 'listNearby' isn't initialized / there is no 0 index yet, so it defaults to the Futurebuilder / .hasNoData and stays there.

---> below is updated from original post

Providing my getSearch future function which seems to be the cause of the issue, by checking the connection status, I can see that it shows connectionStatus.done while it's still looping through the if(listNearby.isEmpty), although I expect it shouldn't show connection complete until I return a value -- all the way at the end of my code.

```
    getSearch() async {
  var listNearbyNew = [];
  print('do we go here?');
  if (listNearby.isEmpty) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
      print('how about here?');
      getSearchFuture = getSearch();
    });
  } else {
    print('did we make it to the else?');
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      DocumentSnapshot gG = await firestore.collection('xxxx').doc(listNearby[i]).get();
      listTest.add(gG.data().toString());
      try {
        for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
          final incremDt = _now.add(Duration(days: x));
          final incremDtFrmtd = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(incremDt);
          var regexp = RegExp(r"(?<=host-).+?(?=:)");
          Iterable<Match> matches = regexp.allMatches(gG.get(incremDtFrmtd).toString(), 0);
          if (matches.isNotEmpty) {
            for (final Match h in matches) {
              String match2 = h[0]!; //hostEmail
              var info = gG.get(incremDtFrmtd)['xxx-$match2']; // this returns the info
              var xxx = info['xxx'];
              List xx = info['xxx'];
              List xx = info['xx'];
              List xxx = info['xxx'];
              listNearbyNew.add({
                ///add list items
              });
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // print(e);
      }
    }
    listNearbyNew.sort((a, b) {
      int dateComp = a['date'].compareTo!(b['date']);
      if (dateComp == 0) {
        return parseTime(a['time'][0]).compareTo(parseTime((b['time'][0])));
      }
      return dateComp;
    });
    print('done');
    return listNearbyNew;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not totlly clear why you have a stream builder and a future builder, they seem to be trying to return the same thing. Would it be fair to say that your problem would be solved if you could get the results of the firebase query directly in the StreamBuilder's `builder` method (and could get rid of the FutureBuilder altogether)?

Comment: BTW it's not a great idea to initialise the stream in the `build` method as it will recreate it every time the widget renders - better to initialise it in `initState`

Comment: @Clive, they actually pull from 2 separate firebase collections, the only common ground between the 2 is the ID which it uses to pull from another collection. I will absolutely move the build method.. it's very 'expensive' to leave it there.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream =
  geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(center: center, radius: 
    radius, field: field);
```

You're creating the stream in the build.  Every time the widget rebuilds (which could be 60 to 120 times per second, especially if there's an animation), the stream will be *restarted*.  This means you'll be forever loading, and rapidly burning through your firebase free tier. (Ouch!)

The solution is to lift that stream into the initState of this widget, or use something like a Riverpod StreamProvider to wrap the value so it gets created only once, and then accessed on multiple build passes.  I have a video that illustrates the problem better at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: Updated my code to match your suggestion, should take up less memory - thanks! Do you have any idea regarding my original question?

Comment: I presume the symptoms have changed.  What else needs fixing?

Comment: Symptoms still seem to be the same, the futurebuilder stays in the default else return "Loading". Right now I am calling a setState to reload the function within this state although that clearly isn't how a futurebuilder works. So I looked at the connection status, it always shows 'waiting', I put a print statement in my getSearch (which is the futurebuilder future), and it shows that the data does complete, although it doesn't trigger my futurebuilder when ready for some reason.

Comment: I have updated my post & code with more detailed information, hopefully this helps! Thank you!

Comment: I did notice that in the code I provided, I must have erased the return, but it returns a list after being sorted! I added more print statements for debugging, it seems to show done connecting when the DocumentSnapshot gG = await etc gets triggered.